# div not limiting itself to be within the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header and a content section

```
 ------------------
|       Header     |
 ------------------
|                  |
|     Content      |
|                  |
|                  |
 ------------------
```

I have used `flex: 1 1 auto; overflow:hidden;` on the content and `overflow:display; flex: 0 1 auto;` on the header. This all is working fine.

Next in the content i have created 4 `<div>` each with 25% height.

```
<div class="content">
            <!--first row-->
            <div class="myrow">
                <div class="colsolid">Johnson </div><!--
                --><div class="col">Coke</div><!--
                --><div class="colsolid">Nissan</div><!--
                --><div class="col">Pepsi</div>
            </div>

            <!--second row-->
            <div class="myrow">
              <div class="colsolid">Johnson </div><!--
                --><div class="col">Coke</div><!--
                --><div class="colsolid">Nissan</div><!--
                --><div class="col">Pepsi</div>
            </div>

            <!--third row-->
            <div class="myrow">
              <div class="colsolid">Johnson </div><!--
                --><div class="col">Coke</div><!--
                --><div class="colsolid">Nissan</div><!--
                --><div class="col">Pepsi</div>
            </div>

            <!--forth row-->
            <div class="myrow">
              <div class="colsolid">Johnson </div><!--
                --><div class="col">Coke</div><!--
                --><div class="colsolid">Nissan</div><!--
                --><div class="col">Pepsi</div>
            </div>          
        </div>
```

**relevant css**

```
.myrow{
height:25%;
background-color: red;
align-items: center;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.col{
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: -webkit-calc(25% - 2px);
    width:    -moz-calc(25% - 2px);
    width:         calc(25% - 2px);
}

.colsolid{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    width: -webkit-calc(25% - 2px);
    width:    -moz-calc(25% - 2px);
    width:         calc(25% - 2px);
}
```

The issue is that the `myrow` are not limiting to be **25%** of the `content` div. Instead its **25%** of the full page height. Any ideas?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2furnxes/2/) link

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as `overflow: display`. That value doesn't exist ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)).

Also, when you give an element a percentage height, Chrome and Safari require that a height be specified on the parent element. Several containers in your HTML structure are missing a defined height, so `height: 25%` on `.myrow` elements may not work.

More details here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)
- [*revised fiddle demo*](https://jsfiddle.net/2furnxes/3/)

---

*UPDATE (based on feedback in the comments):*

On your live site, try this:

- Remove `height: 100%` from `.content`. (`height: 100%` on `.content` *plus* the navbar height exceed 100% and will cause overflow.)
- Make `.content` a flex container: give it `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. This will make all `.myrow` elements flex items.
- Remove `height: 8.33%` from `.myrow` flex items. This isn't necessary anymore. Just give `.myrow` a `flex: 1` rule. This will distribute container height equally among the 12 items.
- Finally, add `min-height: 0` to `.myrow`. This overrides the default `min-height: auto` on flex items, which prevents them from shrinking past the size of their content ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)).

Comment: seems to be working in your fiddle but not in my code.... the only difference is that i split up the css files..

Comment: post more details or a link to a live site so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: here is the link to the site http://actionmary.com/newSite/friends.html

Comment: notice that the last row is getting cut. All 12 rows should have fit on the screen.

Comment: @michaek_B that made it worse. Take a look now.

Comment: That's apparently caused by the `::before` pseudo-element on `.colsolid`. If you remove the `height: 100%` on the pseudo, the text is visible again. However, it messes up the row height.

Comment: yes you are right i just tried that. Any idea how to resolve the height issue?

Comment: that too `content: ''` causes the text to go away. Buts its also what causes the height issue to be addressed in the `::before` blocks